# Do sharks die if they stop swimming?

Tags: zoology, sharks

I've seen this claim several places:

> If a shark stops swimming it will die. (from [wikianswers](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_happens_to_Sharks_when_they_stop_swimming), alongside contradictory text)
>
> [I]f they do not swim, then they will have no oxygen and they will drown. (from [ask.com](http://www.ask.com/question/can-sharks-drown))

Do sharks drown and die if they stop swimming?

Answer (score 14):

In general **no**, but there are some species of sharks that require movement to circulate water over their gills. [NOVA had this question](http://www.pbs.org/wgbh/nova/sharks/masters/myths2.html) addressed to [Dr. Samuel "Sonny" Gruber](http://www.rsmas.miami.edu/people/faculty-index/?p=samuel-h.-gruber) who responded as follows:

> NOVA: Do sharks have to keep swimming to breathe?
>
> Gruber: Several species do, including hammerheads and mackerel sharks.
>   Typically, pelagic sharks that never encounter the bottom are adapted
>   to swim all their lives. But the vast majority of sharks have a buccal
>   (mouth) pump and are not so-called "obligate ram ventilators." (Ram
>   ventilators like hammerheads and great whites must swim to pass water
>   over their gills.) So the answer is no, emphatically. There are even
>   some sharks with spiracles, holes on the top of their head that allow
>   water to enter their gill chambers when the mouth is on the bottom.

This is corroborated by [science](http://dsc.discovery.com/tv-shows/shark-week/about-this-show/can-sharks-drown.htm) and [educational](http://science.howstuffworks.com/zoology/marine-life/shark-drown.htm) websites online as well as in the biology textbooks such as "[Biology of Sharks and Their Relatives, Second Edition](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1439839247)."

[image: Wobbegong shark lying on the bottom of the ocean]

The [Wobbegong shark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wobbegong), a member of the [carpet sharks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carpet_shark) family. As an [ambush predator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambush_predator), the Wobbegong shark demonstrates this behavior by lying in wait on the ocean floor among rocks and other materials waiting for smaller fish to swim closer.

Comment: mind that needing waterflow doesn't mean they have to swim. They could be stationary in flowing water instead...

Comment: As a wonderful example, see the Wobbegong shark - which sits on the bottom, camouflaged, waiting motionless awaiting its prey.

Comment: @RoryAlsop Ah! Good one!

Comment: But it seems there are some sharks that would (Great whites and hammerheads)

Comment: I think, although science has long believed certain sharks needed constant movement, I remember a few instances (very rare) where this has been found not entirely true! http://www.ack.net/sharks080510.html
and 
http://www.sharkwatchsa.com/en/blog/category/482/post/1099/how-white-sharks-sleep/

What I really want to find is the article where the great whites were found sleeping in some underwater cave, but I can't!!!